# How to tell your viewController to update and pass it an object with the update specifics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a general working knowledge of object-oriented programming and I'm currently trying to create an interactive novel program in Objective C using Xcode 4.2 with storyboarding.

I have a storyController class that instantiates the page objects and a viewController class that needs to display the pages. My fundamental question is the best approach for my storyController to tell the viewController to update it's text to display that of the new page object. My instinct tells me that my storyController needs to call a method on the viewController and pass it a page object. However, I'm not sure how to reference the view controller since it seems to be automatically created and linked by the storyboard (I don't see the viewController instantiated in the appDelegate).

I've read this post: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html and it seems to address the issue. I could make a shared object on my appDelegate and use KVN or NSNotification to tell the view controller to check it.

I've also been reading about delegates and protocols as possible solutions.

So considering these potentially different approaches, which would be best to tell my viewController to update itself and pass it an object that contains the updates?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the [UIPageViewController class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html), which probably will do a lot of the heavy lifting work for you, depending on the specifics of your app.  This class is essentially a controller class that contains multiple viewControllers.  Each managed viewController becomes essentially a "page" in your book.

[Here is a tutorial using UIPageViewController.](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application)

If this approach won't work for your app, I'd still suggest using a separate viewController instance for each "page" of your book and handle the transition between the pages with segues.